# How to write a cydia app

Tags: objective-c, jailbreak, cydia

I was wondering about to create a cydia tweak running on iphone startup and hooking some iphone feature as sms or call.

So I wanted to know where should I start:

1. How to write a cydia application (xCode? Toolchain? which toolchain? how to install it?)
2. Where can I found documentation about the hooking methods of the mobile substrate?
3. How can I star my application on iPhone startup?

I'd be glad if someone can link me THE VERY NOOB guide on how to start jb developpement (I juste develop "officially")

Thanks everybody

Comment: This violates multiple Apple License Agreements and cannot be posted on SO.

Comment: @Evan you bought the phone, you can do whatever you want with it.  You dont need to use XCode to create tweaks.

Comment: Surely the fact that Jailbreaking is now deemed legal, plus, you do not need to use Apple developer tools to create these negates the information within the agreements. I love Apple, but they can't just deem things as a violation of their rules when their rules don't apply.

Comment: @EvanMulawski, the Apple license agreement is between the developer and Apple.  It has nothing to do with Stack Overflow.  I paid close attention to this issue during the last moderator election, and Brad Larson (who I believe is the highest rep moderator in the `iOS` tag) made a statement similar to this ... hopefully he steps in if I'm remembering incorrectly.  Second, what the other two comments said.  Third, I'm kind of tired of people trying to push open development content off this site.  All iOS devs would benefit from the knowledge that comes from some of these questions.

Answer (score 1):

I know there are other ways of doing this, but if your a licensed iOS Developer you can simply sign the code in your App and put it on to one of your registered testing Devices that's jailbroken and follow the step by step instructions below:

Download iFile from the Cydia Store. I would suggest paying for it, but you can find other sources where you can get a cracked version. Then use iFile on the device and go into the following directory:
var/mobile/Applications/YourAppName
Select YourAppName.app folder
Tap the zip file button, (between + and trash buttons at bottom of display)
You will be prompted to name the zip file and hit create.
That's the zip file you submit to Cydia, you can email it to yourself from within iFile, or if you want use a program like DiskAid to pull it from your Device.  DONE!

TESTING
To test you need to copy the .app file into the following directory:
var/stash/Applications
Exit iFile and Delete your app from the devise. Respring, Reboot, or Restart.
The icon will then be on your desktop.

HOPE THIS HELPS SOMEONE!!!

Note:  This is against Apple policy, but if you don't tell I won't ;)

Comment: If someone doesn't want to pay for iFile or any other app, then they shouldn't buy it. Please don't advocate software piracy here. There are however free apps similar to iFile, like myFile.